# Is there a good API for locks between web-app clients to avoid conflicting edits?

Tags: api, web-applications, locking

Is there an API or system for managing locks to prevent conflicting edits, between two users of a web app?

I can code my own service for this... But if there is a standard protocol - I'd prefer to implement that. And if there's a good off-the-shelf system, I'd prefer to use that.

Answer (score 0):

(...after some googling) RFC 4918 defines the http methods LOCK and UNLOCK, which gives a standardised RESTful approach. It doesn't seem to be widely used (?), but it is a web standard and so the right thing to implement.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918